# Ошибка EF: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Есть следующие классы:

```
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public Groups? GroupId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Tutor")]
        public int? TutorId { get; set; }
        public Tutor? Tutor { get; set; }
    }

public class Tutor
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ThirdName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

После добавления миграции, при вызове команды Update-Database возникает ошибка создания внешнего ключа. Такая ошибка уже была, и я тогда просто удалил таблицу. Но сейчас не очень хотелось бы это делать. Вдруг в будущем там будут данные, а без удаления никак не добавить функционал. Поэтому хочу узнать о решении проблемы. Перерыл первые страницы, даже на зарубежном SO, но решения кроме как удалить таблицу не нашел. Как исправить ошибку миграции с внешним ключом?

Comment: Миграция - это процесс перехода от одного состояния к другому. Код, который вы показали, это какое из состояний? Что было до миграции и что должно стать после неё? Покажите два кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov до миграции сущность была без внешнего ключа (свойств модели TutorId и Tutor). При попытке создать внешний ключ ошибка. Любые другие миграции и обновления БД проходят успешно

Answer (score -1):

Надо указывать - что является внешним ключом для экземпляра Tutor

```
   public int? TutorId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("TutorId")]
   public Tutor? Tutor { get; set; }
```